# Hashtable in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, hashtable

I have a requirement where I would like to store the key value pairs or hashtable in my SQL Server table as a column.

Can I store a hash table as a column in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Please suggest some alternative if not possible.

Thanks
Prabhanjan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store pretty much anything in a binary field if you want to, including a serialized hashtable object.

But this doesn't sound like a good idea. Why not create a separate table with two columns for the keys and values, respectively?